# SQLiteOpenHelper Erro(8,8)

Tags: android-studio, sqlite

Estou começando a programar em *Android* e quero fazer uma classe com um banco de dados.

```
package josephisaac.com.wmvendas;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class BancoDados extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

}
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){

    }
}
```

Quando digito o código acima no meu *Android Studio* e executo, ele aparece o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Error:(8, 8) error: no suitable constructor found for
> SQLiteOpenHelper(no arguments) constructor
> SQLiteOpenHelper.SQLiteOpenHelper(Context,String,CursorFactory,int) is
> not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
> constructor SQLiteOpenHelper.SQLiteOpenHelper (Context, String, CursorFactory, int, DatabaseErro
> Handler) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in
> length)
> ```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: É recomendável que coloque código ao invés de imagens.

Comment: @JoãoMartins editei

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015731/android-sqlite-example